# Mixed MVC4 into existing ASP.NET Webforms project and now strongly typed views don't recognize the type of the model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I'm attempting to add MVC4 functionality to an existing webforms project.  I've followed steps outlined in these articles:

http://blogs.ibs.com/Scott.Zischerk/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=20

http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-aspnet-webforms-and-aspnet-mvc

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx

The main difference between my scenario and the all of the examples provided is that i'm not trying to get this to work with Razor.  I'm perfectly happy for my views to be oldschool Aspx.

So far, the routing aspect works quite well and the correct controllers are hit and function as expected. I can successfully put things into ViewData and consume it on the appropriate view.  Everything up until the point of strongly typing the view works delightfully.

When i attempt to make a strongly typed view, things fail giving an error message of:

" 'object' does not contain a definition for 'someProperty'... "

Here is an example of a test view that doesn't work as expected:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/MVC.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TDS.Domain.Entities.SomeEntity>"  %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2> <%= Model.someProperty%></h2>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

I'm stumped here because i believe i've followed all directions to get MVC4 to play nice with the existing Webforms project. Everything else MVC-y is working as expected.  One thing i haven't been able to figure out is what links up the "Inherits" page property with the appropriate model binder? This is my best guess as to what might be missing.

EDIT:
Haven't been able to solve this, but this is the hacky workaround i've come up with for the time being. Instead of returning the model to the view like:

```
return View(retVal);
```

I've resorted to stuff it in the ViewBag like this:

```
ViewBag.Model = retVal;
```

and then accessing it at the very top of the view like this:

```
<% var Model = (WhateverType)ViewBag.Model; %>
```

Super hacky, but achieves the same goal. :(

2ND EDIT:

Here is the bit from the webconfig as requested.

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Controller code:

```
        SomeEntity retVal = new SomeEntity();
        using (TDS.Domain.TdsDatabase tds = new TDS.Domain.TdsDatabase())
        {
            retVal = tds.SomeEntitys.First(x => x.Id == 36);
        }
        return View(retVal);
```

Comment: May be it is strange, but I also have had the same problem after marging MVC and WebForms projects and solution was just to reboot VisualStudio. After that it started working.

Comment: That might be the solution, append to me with Razor pages as well

Comment: The view you demonstrated is not *Razor View Engine* syntax, its a [WebForms View Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.webformviewengine(v=vs.108).aspx).

Comment: You need to provide your controller code for the view you have given the example for.  Also provide the following values from the web config runtime->assemblybinding->dependentassembly-> all assemblyIdentity and bindingredirect nodes.

Comment: As written in my OP: "The main difference between my scenario and the all of the examples provided is that i'm NOT trying to get this to work with Razor. I'm perfectly happy for my views to be oldschool Aspx."

Comment: Added web config bits and controller code. Controller seems to be working as designed.

Comment: @ErikPhilips You were right. I was missing stuff in that section of the web config. I copy pasted a section from a working MVC4 project and everything works. If you want to post an answer, i'll accept it.

Comment: Ahh sorry I misread your comment, I though you were trying to get razor to work (my bad).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be missing some key MVC Assemblies in the web.config:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: I copied in these from another MVC4 solution and it worked! System.Web.WebPages.Razor, System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, System.Web.Razor

Comment: One final comment, i found this counter-intuitive because i was NOT trying to use Razor anywhere in this project but it seems the addition of these assemblies in the web config fixed the issue.

Comment: That behavior is VERY odd indeed.